# Vaio Laptop - Battery Level Indicator stays at 100% always

Tags: laptop, battery, sony-vaio

I have Sony Vaio VPCYB15AG Notebook, Windows 7 OS and its battery is about one and a half years old. After being fully charged, the %level indicator always shows 100% no matter how much it has discharged.

Taking input from [HP Forum](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Software-and-How-To-Questions/Battery-Indicator-shows-100-charged-at-all-times/m-p/3062671), I uninstalled ‘Microsoft ACPI Compliant Battery’ from device manager and restarted the laptop so that it gets reinstalled automatically upon reboot. This worked but now I have to do it every time battery is charged to 100%, else the % level stays at 100%.

I looked at a similar [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/654337/vaio-pro-battery-level-not-updating-while-using)   on Superuser but there’s no Vaio Power Management Service as mentioned therein in my Windows 7.

I ran BatteryInfoView software and battery wear level is around 52% so far, which is still acceptable.

There is no option in BIOS to calibrate the battery as a separate process.

Is there any permanent fix to this issue or do I have a dying battery? I wish to avoid uninstalltion of Battery from the Device Manager everytime after charging.

[image]

Comment: "but there’s no Vaio Power Management Service" - There would be if you installed it.  It sounds like you should do that to resolve the odd behavior you describe.

Comment: Power Management software utility is not applicable for this model. Manually calibrating the battery, i.e. one full discharge and full charge cycle seems to have resolved this issue.